# AppleScript Command Works in Terminal but not in Java

Tags: java, javafx, terminal, applescript, runtime

**My main question is how can I make the command mentioned below work in java, The main problem in this command is it does not do script that I commanded it to execute; can someone help me make this apple script work in java?**

I do not understand but for some reason the command:

`osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "cd /Users/benjaminsloutsky/eclipse-workspace/stack/Stack/StackProjects/Brother/build && cmake .. && cmake --build . && ./cmake-good"'`

executes in the terminal, but whenever I try to run it in java using Runtime.getRuntime().exec() command it does not execute at all (it does not show me a new terminal window with code being execucted, but works in terminal). The whole point of this command is to show a new terminal with the output of the main.cpp file. This is my java code:

```
final String innerCommand = 
     "cd /Users/benjaminsloutsky/eclipse-workspace/stack/Stack/StackProjects/Brother/build && cmake .. && cmake --build . && ./cmake-good";
String[] comm = new String[] {
     "/bin/bash", "-c", 
     "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"" +
     innerCommand + "\"'"
};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comm);
```

it does not run. Why is that and how could I fix this issue so my script could also run in javafx. The point of this command is to show a new terminal window and then run a script.

I thought that I am running multiple commands correctly as listed in my `comm` variable and I am executing the command with runtime.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Works for me... Note that the terminal window might not be automatically focused.

Comment: It works for you in java?

Comment: Its just a typo.  The final `'` shouldn't be there.

Comment: @StephenC I do not understand what you mean, I have a ```'``` before ```tell```and I have a ```'``` after ```\"```

Comment: Change `"\"'"` to `"\""`  in your Java code.  The `'` should not be there.

Comment: @StephenC I did but it still does not make a difference?

Comment: Ah.  OK, I see now.  But I had to fix your overly long Java lines to make it clear what was going on.

Comment: So when you say "it does not run" ... what actually happens?

Comment: It does not show a new terminal window and terminal does not run any build functionality in java, while in the terminal when I run the command, all that functionality works and a new terminal shows.

Comment: Is the terminal window being opened *behind* the current window; see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/205143

Comment: I tried doing this ```String[] comm = new String[] {
                     "/bin/bash", "-c",
                     "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to activate' && "
                     + "osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"" +
                             innerCommand + "\"'"
             };``` but it still does not work, the terminal was never showing

Comment: Try getting it to *just* open a terminal and echo something.

Comment: don't delete and repost the same question! Instead edit the first to make it answerable.

Comment: You figured wrong.  Reposting a question is a major no-no.  Reposting is interpreted by people here as "attention seeking behavior".  You are liable to find that the repost heavily downvoted and then dup-closed.  The (only) legitimate way to draw attention to a question on StackOverflow is to post a Bonus.

Comment: I re-edited this question, I realized that my main problem is that it is not executing the "do script" command in java!

Answer (score 2):

`Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` is not the best way to run and manage the external processes in Java, its better to use the `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` instead.

So your code can be expressed in `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` like this.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class CommandExecutor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CommandExecutor executor = new CommandExecutor();
        executor.executeInTerminal("cd /Users/benjaminsloutsky/eclipse-workspace/stack/Stack/StackProjects/Brother/build && cmake .. && cmake --build . && ./cmake-good");
    }

    public void executeInTerminal(String command){
        List<String> cms = new ArrayList<>();
        cms.add("/bin/sh");
        cms.add("-c");
        cms.add("osascript -e 'tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"" + command + "\"'");

        ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        processBuilder.command(cms);
        try {

            Process process = processBuilder.start();

            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

             String line;
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line + "\n");
            }

            boolean success = process.waitFor(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            // check the status
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            // do some logging
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How come this works perfectly in java but not in javafx?

Comment: @BenjaminSloutsky there should not be any difference, do you have a code snippet which shows how are you executing it ?

Comment: Yes, I basically do the same thing as you are doing but when a button is being pressed in javafx: ```play.setOnAction```

Comment: @BenjaminSloutsky are you running in main thread ?

Comment: That can be a problem, try with Platform.runLater

Comment: Tried doing it, still no luck

Comment: That can be a problem with your IO, try `processBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.PIPE);processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);` or `processBuilder.inheritIO().start()` otherwise share a code which does not work.